# Ionic v2 build ios error with ionic-app-scripts build

Tags: ios, npm, ionic2

Ionic v2 not able to compile for IOS.

getting error

```
11 silly lifecycle tr@~build: Args: [ '-c', 'ionic-app-scripts build' ]
12 silly lifecycle tr@~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle tr@~build: Failed to exec build script
14 verbose stack Error: tr@ build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1

[12:20:56]  Error: Cannot determine the module for component CustomNavbar! 
[12:20:56]  ngc failed 
[12:20:56]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[12:20:56]  Error: Error 

error Darwin 15.6.0
18 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
19 error node v7.0.0
20 error npm  v3.10.8
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error tr@ build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the tr@ build script 'ionic-app-scripts build'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the tr package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     ionic-app-scripts build
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs tr
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls tr
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Ionic serve is working properly and displaying the preview app
but not able to build for ios.

Comment: Can you share your code please ?

Answer (score 0):

remove unnecessary folder and export class " CustomNavbar "
to resolve the issue.

Error: Cannot determine the module for component CustomNavbar!

Comment: Please you can share your code for extra information about your problem ?